# Unix | Spark - setting positional variables with whitespaces

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, unix, scripting

I have a requirement where i have to pass a filter condition as a param to a shell bash script

```
eg "col IN ('abc')"
```

This works fine, when i directly pass it via spark submit.
I want to create a bash shell script and pass it via the shell script like

```
./shell.sh "col IN ('abc')"
```

Now, the problem i am facing in above shell script approach is, even though i pass the param in double quotes but still the bash-4.1 splits it into multiple params which further breaks my spark code.

I know i can backslash the param quotes in the shell script and feed it to EVAL function and make it work, becoz below worked for me, but the issue is, i have to give this 1 line script to a non-programming person (he knows basic SQL only) and dont want to confuse him with managing backslashes everytime he runs the program.

```
./shell.sh "\"col IN ('abc')\""
```

i tried lot of manipulation as well on the param and then setting it again via

```
set -- param
```

But again bash splits it up into multiple params.
Is there a easy way to fix this in the shell script ??

Please help.

Comment: `for i in $*` is innately, irresolvably buggy. It serves no useful purpose and should never be run by anyone.

Comment: If you want to list your arguments, one per line, that's `printf '%s\n' "$@"`, or `for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: ...that is to say: `"$*"` takes all your arguments, and mashes them together into a single string. Then when you use `$*` _unquoted_, that string gets split out into individual words again. Thus, how `for i in $*` behaves tells you **nothing at all** about whether you originally had a single argument or three separate ones, because you get the same undesired behavior either way.

Comment: ...to be clear, you may well have a real problem, but the [mre] given doesn't demonstrate it, because it would show the same output even if your parameter-passing were 100% perfect.

Comment: (```shell.sh "\"col IN ('abc')\""``` **shouldn't** fix anything, because the inner `"`s are literal; for them to be syntactic something needs to be `eval`ing your data, or passing it in a context where it's treated as code to an inner shell, or doing something else comparably nasty; but you aren't showing us the code where any of those things happens, so we can't help you fix it; the problem you _are_ giving us enough information to fix is the problem in the test case itself, caused by using `$*` instead of `"$@"`).

Comment: sorry, i wasnt clear on my question. U r right, $@ prints the param in 1 line with whitespaces as well. Actually, (shell.sh "\"col IN ('abc')\"" this i tried via eval, feeding this into EVAL. Thing is, $@ is printing the param in 1 line, no issues, but the same $@ i am passing to the spark-submit as well. When i print the args array received within my spark program, the "col IN ('abc')" is splitted into further multiple params. Sorry, if i am still not clear, as to i am also not sure, why its happening.

Comment: i have edited my question, since $@ works fine and is printing whitespaces args as well inside the unix program in 1 line. But the same $@ fed to the spark submit, splits the whitespaces param into multiple params, causing issue for me in the program, pls help.

Comment: i resolved it, i was passing $@ to the spark submit which split the params. After passing "$@", i was able to get the whitespace params as well in 1 single param, wheeww, very weird, but solved it, thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy for the help :) Really appreciated :)